# Coldfusion: how to access nested array of structures

Tags: arrays, data-structures, coldfusion, nested

[image]

I am trying to access tax_lines.item and tax_lines.price, but not successful.
Here is what I run:

```
<cfif structKeyExists( jsonData, 'orders' ) AND isArray(jsonData.orders)>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(jsonData.orders)#" index="i">
        <cfset line_items = jsonData.orders[i].line_items>
        <cfif not arrayIsEmpty(#line_items#)>
            <cfloop array="#line_items#" index="i"> 
            ......
            ........
            <cfset item_tax_lines = line_items[i].tax_lines>                    
                <cfif not arrayIsEmpty(#item_tax_lines#)>
                ....
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not successful"? Error, wrong result, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `line_items[i].tax_lines`

That causes an error because you're using an array loop. So the index variable `i` contains the current element of the array - not a position number. To access the tax_lines key, use `i.tax_lines` instead.

> `<cfif not arrayIsEmpty(#line_items#)>
>       <cfloop array="#line_items#" index="i">`

Not related to the error, but the arrayIsEmpty check isn't necessary. If the array is empty, the loop will do nothing. So you could simplify the loop code to just this:

```
<cfloop array="#jsonData.orders#" index="order">
    <cfloop array="#order.line_items#" index="line">
        do something with #line.tax_lines# here ....
     </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I edited original image for you to see what I am trying to do. 

`<cfloop array="#line_items#" index="line">    
 <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(line.tax_lines)#" index="i"> 
  <cfoutput>
   #i.title#<br />
   #i.rate#<br />
   #i.price#    
  </cfoutput>    
 </cfloop>
</cfloop>` results in Error: You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.Double as a structure with members.

Comment: Now you have the opposite problem :-)  The inner most loop is a from/to cfloop. That type of cfloop populates the index variable `i` with a numeric position - not an array element.  Unless you actually need the position for something, best to stick with the same loop type throughout, i.e. "array" loop. `<cfloop array="#line.tax_lines#" index="curr_tax_line">#curr_tax_line.title# ... </cfloop>`

Answer (score 1):

I like Ageax's solution. I would just do it in `<cfscript>`

```
<cfscript>
for (order in jsonData.orders) {
   for (line in  order.line_items) {
       // fancy stuff with line.tax_lines#
   }
 }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: That'd be my preference too, but given the cfml in the question, and history, I decided to stick with what they're using.